# How to set docker image name using sbt-native-packager

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm working on multi-module project in Lagom framework and building it using SBT. I successfully configured my project to generate docker images using sbt-native-packager.
The only problem I have is that those images have 'funny' names (e.g.: 'brave_meninsky', 'loving_archimedes', 'vigilant_ride' etc.) and I would like to name them differently.

How can I set custom docker image name using sbt-native-packager?

I was unable to find the answer in [the docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html).

I use the following versions:

SBT: 0.13.13

scala: 2.11.8

sbt-native-packager: 1.2.0-M9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html#docker-image-name) says to set the `packageName` in the `Docker` scope to change the image name.

However, the examples you give seem to be container names. To set the name of a container when using `docker run`, use the `--name` flag:

```
docker run --name a_better_name my_image_name:tag
```

Comment: That's true! Thanks.
I confused image name with docker container name which made me wonder why it doesn't work.
I actually used packageName and it set the image name correctly - exactly what documentations says.